# How can i add a "like" button in a Django class ListView

Tags: django, listview

I am pulling my hair out trying to add a "like" button in my site´s post app, but as i want to add it in a ListView  that contains the rest of the posts entries and everyone has the option to be commented I have added a Formixin to do so, so, now i cannot add another form for the like button as it would mean two posts requests....so  I am not finding a clear solution... I have read here and there about using AJAX or Json techs but as im new programing im kind of stuck in it... has anyone any tip to offer?

Answer (score 0):

While using AJAX (javascript XHR requests) would be the proper way so the page doesn't need to be refreshed when just clicking a like button, you can do it without AJAX.

#### HTML

On the HTML side of things, you can have multiple forms (`<form>`), one for each post, which have a hidden input field that's the post's id. You have set that explicitly in the HTML template, e.g.

```html
{% for post in post_list %}
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
    <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="hidden" value="{{ post.id }}" name="{{ form.id.html_name }}">
       <input type="submit">Like</input>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

So basically you're reusing the form multiple times, changing the "value" attribute to match the post.

#### Django Form

Adding the `FormMixin` to your view is the right step, just use the `form_class` to a custom `LikeForm` with just one field that's an IntegerField called `id`.

#### View

By adding the `FormMixin` you get the `form_valid()` method, which you'll want to override to save the like:

```python
def form_valid(self, form):
    id = form.cleaned_data['id']
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    post.likes.add(self.request.user)  # assuming likes is a m2m relation to user
    return redirect('post_list')  # this list view
```

Comment: thanks Dirk, I see your point doing the things right by using Ajax, so i want to do it correctly and I am going to try to implement it although I have seen that I can use two modelforms, within the same HTML form so by this means it only contains a unique Post request...but still I you are right and I want the like being updated without the need to reload the url, thanks, im gonna try your AJAX proposal!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am not so late, I had similar challenges trying to implement the same functionalities on my website.
I came to realize that each button id should be unique (Preferably the post id if blog), but the classes can be the same.
I was able to solve it. Here is an article I wrote on medium recently on the steps I followed to so get this working you can check it out [here](https://michealscode.medium.com/django-ajax-like-and-upvote-button-on-listview-solved-in-5-simple-steps-96dbdc39daca)

Comment: Hi there I just saw your reply and want to thank you, I finally cope with it usin ajax so I had to learn it which by the way i have learnt that is a must nowadays in the field.. thanks anyway!!